# Providing a single instance of a provider for multiple instances of a component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am creating a component dynamically with the following code

```ts
  addPhone(): void {
    const widgetFactory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory( PhoneComponent );
    this.createdWidgetRef =
        this.container.createComponent( widgetFactory );
    this.createdWidgetRef.instance.index = this.container.length - 1;
    this.createdWidgetRef.instance.containerRef = this.container;
    ++this.containerIndex
  }
```

The component is created alright.

I have an ObservableMap that I would like to have only a single instance to be used for all instances of the PhoneComponent created dynamically. I cannot put this ObservableMap in the PhoneComponent because a new instance of the map will be created for each PhoneComponent instance (at least this is what occurs now). This occurs with injecting the ObservableMap as a service.

Is there some way to use angular2 service to accomplish this task?

NB: All data entered into the different instances of the PhoneComponent should be inserted into the single instance of ObservableMap - so only a single instance must be present for multiple instances of the component.

Further, I cannot use the provider in bootstrap because I will need to use the ObservableMap for other components as well (for example EmailComponent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the service in an `NgModule` that is not lazy loaded

```ts
@Injectable() 
export class SharedMapService {
  private _sharedMap = {};
  get sharedMap() { return this._sharedMap; }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [SharedMapService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

add this constructor to your `PhoneComponent`

```ts
constructor(private sharedMap:SharedMapService) {
  console.log(sharedMap.sharedMap);
}
```

Comment: Hi Gunther. Thanks. But could you please explain why this guarantees a single instance of the map for multiple instances of PhoneComponent?

Comment: "guarantee" is a strong word. If you don't do anything that causes other instances than it should be safe enough. Angular2 maintains a single instance per provider. If the service is only provided in `@NgModule()` of non-lazy-loaded modules, then Angular2 will ensure there the same instance of the service be injected. If you don't create copies of the map in the service yourself, then there will ever be only this single instance inside the service.

Comment: Would the data saved in PhoneComponent1 and PhoneComponent2 be saved to the same instance of the map provided by the service in the above suggestion? (which is what I would like). Or would each PhoneComponent has its own instance of the map to save its data (which is what I do NOT want). If AppModule above refers to the bootstrap module, this will not work for me because if I have another component EmailComponent and wants to save its data to the map, it would now be saved to the same map as the PhoneComponent (which is what I would NOT want)

Comment: I don't know why you think `EmailComponent` would save to the same map. You can have a `PhoneMapService` and a `EmailMapService` and inject the former only to `PhoneComponent`s and the later only to `EmailComponent`s. I updated the code so that you can't accidentally overwrite the map and get an error if you don't assign into the existing map instance but instead (accidentally) override it with a different one.

Comment: It turns out that I have quite a few components that will require their individual instance of the map for multiple components - Email- and Phone-Components being only two. I am wondering if there is a way to prevent the 1:1 Component:Service creation.

Comment: You can have one service with different map properties.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestions now.